# confusion about gamma and gamma portfolios

Tags: investing, options, portfolio, option-strategies, volatility

> Generally, a long gamma portfolio will make money when the underlying: 
> (a) out-realizes the historical volatility (measured close to close) 
> (b) out-realizes the implied volatility (more than making up for theta paid)

Question from a course. Correct answer was (a). Why is it the first answer and not the second? I thought implied volatility was the one that was used to originally price options, not historical. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greeks are mainly used for hedging purposes (and performance attribution). If you delta hedge, gamma essentially tells you have frequently you need to rebalance.

However, from a portfolios overall gamma position, you can say what happens if teh underlying fluctuates a lot or little. Therefore, long gamma is being long realized volatility. Being Long implied vol would be equivalent to being long vega.

You can read some more [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/38363/54838) and [there](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/70751/54838).

P.S. Implied Vol is used to price options, but that is not the question in this case. I am a bit puzzled by the terminology used (underlying out-realizing). I have never heard of this phrase being used but it does not change the underlying idea.